# Action dispatched using the useDispatch but the reducer won't update the state until I refresh the page

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, firebase-authentication, react-hooks

I'm trying to implement Sign Out feature for my web app. The Sign In feature works perfectly but facing issue in sign Out.

I can login and receive the uid from firebase and get the "Login Success" in the console as soon as I press Login button, but, when I press the Logout button *I don't receive the "Signout success" in the console **until I refresh the Page.***

How can this refresh thing be solved?

I have my action creator `signOut` in place as seen below:

```
export const signOut = () => {
    return (dispatch, getState, {fetFirebse}) => {
        const firebase = getFirebase();

        firebase.auth().signOut().then(() => {
            dispatch({ type: 'SIGNOUT_SUCCESS'})
        });
    }
}
```

This is the component where I `dispatch` the `signOut` action using the `useDispatch` hook:

```
const SignedInLinks = (props) => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    dispatch(signOut());

     

    return ( 
        <ul className="right">
            <li><NavLink to='/create'>New Project</NavLink></li>
            <li><a onClick={props.signOut}>Log Out</a></li>
            <li><NavLink to='/' className='btn btn-floating pink lighten-1'>NB</NavLink></li>
        </ul>
     );
}
export default SignedInLinks;
```

And finally here is the `reducer`:

```
const initState = {
    authError: null,
}

const authReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'LOGIN_ERROR':
            console.log('Login Failed');
            return {
                ...state,
                authError: 'Login Failed',
            }
        case 'LOGIN_SUCCESSFUL':
            console.log('Login Success');
            return {
                ...state,
                authError: 'Login Success',
            }
        case 'SIGNOUT_SUCCESS':
            console.log('Signout success');
            return state;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

PS: The signout feature works when I implement it without hooks and use `mapDispatchToProps` and `connect`, but want to know how this refresh needed to update the state can be solved using hooks.

Comment: " props.signOut " You pass signOut to your SignedInLinks ? is this another function ? I'm confused

Comment: You want onClick={() => dispatch(signOut())}

Comment: Do you mean to immediately dispatch the signout action every time the component renders? I think you meant to dispatch that only when the logout button is clicked, i.e. as a callback `onClick={() => dispatch(signOut())}>`.

Comment: No, I don't want to immediately dispatch the sign out action at every render, only when I click the Log out link i want to see the signout success but it won;t show until I refresh.

Comment: Then move it from the function body to the link's onClick handler. And I suggest instead of an anchor tag, link to a signout route that issues the side-effect of logging out and redirecting back to a homepage or whatever.

Comment: @LindaPaiste A big thanks, it worked, I completely forgot that we can dispatch the action on every click in the onClick event listener. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry I cant follow the logic in your components, why SignedInLinks just dispatch the log out after being declared, where are the hooks that notices your state (useSelector for example)?? give us more code to be able to understand